# Installing custom made apps using windows apps studio certificate

Tags: 8.0, 7.x

I have made a custom app for my mobile (windows phone 8) using windows phone 7.1 SDK. I dont have a developer account in windows phone because of this i am unable to install my app in my mobile. Is it possible to use the certificate genertated by windows app studio (for some other apps) to  install my app created using SDK?

Comment: This is off topic here. Voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `developer unlock` your phone to be able to deploy `.xap` files to your phone. If you don't have an account you can ask someone else to unlock you your phone.

I am not sure if you can unlock one phone from the [App Sudio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/Dashboard/Index) but you can read a bit there and see if there is something that helps you